# Exporting a txt file with line record length greater than 32767 characters?

Tags: file, sas

I have been trying to export a SAS data set with 49 variables.  Each of these variables can potentially be 32767 characters long.  I want to write this data set to a txt file, but SAS limits me with the `lrecl` option at 32767 characters.  Is there a way to do this?  I tried using the data step.

```
data _null_;
%let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
%let _EFIREC_ = 0;     /* clear export record count macro variable */
file 'C:path\TEST.txt';
if _n_ = 1 then do;
   put "<BLAH>"
   ;
end;
set  WORK.SAS_DATASET   end=EFIEOD;
   format raw1 $32767. ;
   format raw2 $32767. ;

   etc...
 do;
   EFIOUT + 1;
   put raw1 $ @;
   put raw2 $ @;

   etc...
   ;
 end;
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
if EFIEOD then
 do;
   put "</BLAH>"
   ;
   call symputx('_EFIREC_',EFIOUT);
 end;
run;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  You just need to specify the LRECL yourself.

```
filename test temp;
data _null_;
set sashelp.class;
file test lrecl=999999;
put
@1 name $32767.
@32768 sex $32767.
@65535 age 8.
;;;;
run;
```

Some OSs might limit your logical record length, but it's at least 1e6 in Windows so you should be okay.

Comment: Awesome... I made the mistake of defining it prior to my data step using the `options lrecl=10000000;` statement which gave me an error.

Comment: For some reason, OPTIONS LRECL only allows up to 32767, despite higher LRECLs certainly being legal on the `FILE` statement.

Comment: Okay... ran the code, but it is only writing the first 8000 characters of each variable. Why is that? Is there another option I need to change?

Comment: What are the formats/lengths?  I would expect to find that $8000. format was on the variables - or perhaps something upstream is truncating them.  Are you sure they display all 32767 characters in SAS?

Comment: This works... I found the issue of truncation is not a SAS issue.  I'm pulling a table from a SQL server through ODBC, and that is where the data is getting truncated.